# unknown %27 in my search text. why?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this data for my ajax parameter

`data: param ="searchField="+txtSearch+"&office="+localStorage.getItem("office")+"&person="+localStorage.getItem("person")+"&user="+localStorage.getItem("user")+"&organization="+localStorage.getItem("organization"),`

and in my address bar I get

`http://msw-wsdl.company.net/mobile.asmx/ContactGet?searchField=%27test&office=97&person=119&user=531&organization=14`

if i take out the `27%` the query returns data as needed.

I turned to google and I read it is an a " ' " apostrophe, but I don't use one there.
What else can cause this?

JavaScript:

```
function initContactView() {

    var txtSearch = $("#searchTextField").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: param = "searchField="+txtsearch+"&office="+localStorage.getItem("office")+"&person="+localStorage.getItem("person")+"&user="+localStorage.getItem("user")+"&organization="+localStorage.getItem("organization"),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://smw-wsdl.company.net/mobile.asmx/ContactGet",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successContact,
        failure: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
} 


/*wsdl call succeed*/
function successContact(data) {
    //apply datasource to listview
    $("#lstView_contacts").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource: JSON.parse(data.d),
        template: $("#lstView_contact_Template").html(),
        endlessScroll: true,
        scrollThreshold: 8
    });
```

HTML

`<input required='required' class='txt_input' type='text' placeholder="e.g. Cape Town or 244 Jean Avenue or Jhon Doe" id='searchTextField'/>`

Comment: And where is `txtSearch` coming from?

Comment: Double check that the `txtSearch` variable doesn't contain the apostrophe

Comment: "but I don't use one there" I am pretty sure you do one way or another

Comment: it's the textbox on my html page?

Comment: @shrewdbeans I am pretty sure, I just search test.

Comment: @PeeHaa I have pasted my code exactly, trust me im sure

Comment: Show us all the relevant code

Comment: Pretty sure is not sure. Run `txtSearch.indexOf("'")` or something.

Comment: @PeeHaa I have added code in my question

Comment: And why do you think the ajax call changes the URL in the addressbar?

Comment: @PeeHaa Not sure if question or sarcastic, but I didn't think that. I just though maybe something just went wrong.

Comment: Question, because at first you only shared a piece of code used for the ajax call

Comment: @PeeHaa because that is where I use that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass GET params in JSON format. Try to change **data** param like this:

```
{"searchField":txtsearch,"office":localStorage.getItem("office"),"person":localStorage.getItem("person"),"user":localStorage.getItem("user"),"organization":localStorage.getItem("organization")}
```

Comment: tried that:I get                                               `function initContactView(){var txtSearch=$("#searchTextField").val();$.ajax({type:"GET",data:param="searchField="+txtsearch+"&office="+localStorage.getItem("office")+"&person="+localStorage.getItem("person")+"&user="+localStorage.getItem("user")+"&organization="+localStorage.getItem("organization"),contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",url:"http://wms-wsdl.entegral.net/mobile.asmx/ContactGet",dataType:"json",success:successContact,failure:function(msg){console.log(msg);}});}`    Uncaught referenceError: txt Is not defined

Comment: It seems this error refers to your original code. Also pay attention to cases in `txtSearch` variable.